# How to cite beamer templates

Tags: beamer, citing, templates

It  may be a very basic question, but what is an appropriate way to cite/reference a beamer template?

I have seen many presentations which rely on specific example templates ([examples](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/industrial-training/ncspjhbnwnkc)) and I was wondering, how can we actually cite the templates that we might use, at the end of our presentations?

Thanks

Comment: In most cases you can choose yourself if and how you would like to reference the template. You could for example put a line on your last slide that says "This presentation is typeset using the \LaTeX beamer package with the template XYZ (url)" but there are many variations possible - there is no standard way.

Comment: Thank you @Marijn. I have seen people using templates without references and I think is wrong and unfair towards the people who created them. Your suggestion looks good.